# How to store the Shapefile M attribute in Geopandas/Shapely?

Tags: python, shapefile, shapely, geopandas

Let's say I  have a `geopandas.GeoDataFrame` with a `shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon` as geometry type.

The problem is that I have an attribute per vertex of the polygon, which could theoretically be stored in the shapefile's `M` slot. The only problem is that I could not find an option to include this `M` into the polygon. The [shapely documentation](https://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#polygons) says:

> The Polygon constructor takes two positional parameters. The first is an ordered sequence of (x, y[, z]) point tuples [...]

Further, when using the geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_file method, I couldn't find an option to insert this kind of information.

Can anyone help?

Comment: If Z is not reserved use that instead of M.

Comment: Good point! Unfortuntately, Z is indeed used in some of the polygons I have...

Comment: I fear that you must put the vertices into a new point layer with vertex index as one attribute and save the measures into another attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shapely only considers Cartesian coordinates. M – which exists in the shapefile format so we can record accurate distance between points on otherwise roughly digitized lines (mile markers, etc) – is outside of Shapely's scope.

Comment: Thanks @sgillies! Probably the correct answer to the question!